# Can I access a variable a different stages of the request pipeline in Ruby on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there a way of storing a query in a request level cache or is there a best practice I should be following to achieve the same results that I would get using .NET?

I'm a .NET developer who is working on RoR 3 application. I'm new to RoR

I noticed in the logs that the same model queries were happening in multiple places in a single web request. Once in a controller and again via a Helper on a Partial View.

In .NET I could query the DB and store the result in a memory location, this data would be available to any controller, helper, concern or view throughout the life of the request. The memory is released automatically at the end of request pipeline, thus providing much better performance without tight coupling or having to pass models all around and the approach has loose coupling.

RUBY Model

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :latitude, :location, :longitude, :expires_at, :state, :postcode, :city, :country, :source

  def self.sydney
    where(city: 'SYDNEY', state: 'NSW').first unless where(city: 'SYDNEY', state: 'NSW').blank?
  end
end
```

.NET Model and Call to get DB or Cached data

```
public class LocationData
{
    public string City { get; set; }

    public string State { get; set; }

    public double Longitude { get; set; }

    public double Latitude { get; set; }
}

public static LocationData GetSydneyData()
{
    # Request Level Dictionary/HashTable

    var requestScopedHashTable = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items;

    # 2nd or greater time this method is called in a specific incoming request
    if (requestScopedHashTable.Contains("SydneyData"))
    {
        # Use cached version of the data
        return requestScopedHashTable["SydneyData"] as LocationData;
    }

    # 1st time this method is called in a specific incoming request
    # Query Database, store in request scope object, return the data
    requestScopedHashTable.Add("SydneyData", LocationMode.GetSuburb("Sydney"));

    # Use cached version of the data
    return requestScopedHashTable["SydneyData"] as LocationData;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, this conditional is redundant:

```
unless where(city: 'SYDNEY', state: 'NSW').blank?
```

If it's not `blank`, you'll just execute the same query again to get the result.
The DB adapter used by Rails **might** be smart enough to cache the query and the result, but it's still not very efficient.
(Also, in this case it's more idiomatic to use `any?` rather than `blank?`, as it just checks if the SQL `count` is greater than 0)

The solution you're looking for is memoization:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.sydney
    @sydney ||= where(city: 'SYDNEY', state: 'NSW').first
  end
end
```

The snippet above is the typical way to do it, but since `||=` relies on the left-operand being truthy, if `where().first` returns `nil` the query will **still** be executed with each invocation.

The question is: what kind of result do you expect? Does Sydney always exist? If it doesn't, and you realistically expect `nil`, this could be a better approach:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.sydney
    if @_executed
      @sydney
    else
      @_executed = true
      @sydney = where(city: 'SYDNEY', state: 'NSW').first
    end
  end
end
```

(remember that undefined `@ivars` evaluate to `nil`, which is falsy)

If, on the other hand, you expect Sydney to be always present and unmutable (as if it were a static constant that just happens to live in the DB), the best solution is to store it in a `CONSTANT` and load it only once, on application startup:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base

  SYDNEY = Proc.new do
    Location.where(city: 'SYDNEY', state: 'NSW').first
  end.call

  def self.sydney
    SYDNEY
  end
end
```